# Ember manual url change does not load page

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, url-routing

I have an EmberJS application using Coffeescript and Ember 2.7.1.

I redirect the `/` to `/student`.

When I open my application, let's say on `www.something.com/~somebody/dist/` (yes, I need the `~somebody/dist` part), it goes to `www.something.com/~somebody/dist/student` as expected.

I also have other pages, for example `/settings`. If I use a `link-to` helper to go to the settings page, it works. When I manually change the url from `www.something.com/~somebody/dist/student` to `www.something.com/~somebody/dist/settings`, it doesn't load the page.

I get a *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)* error.

Any idea how to fix this?

My *router.coffee* file:

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`
`import config from './config/environment'`

Router = Ember.Router.extend
    location: config.locationType,
    rootURL: config.rootURL

Router.map ->
    @route 'student'
    @route 'settings'
    @route 'statistics'
    @route 'directory'

`export default Router`
```

My *routes/index.coffee* file:

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`

IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  beforeModel: ->
      @transitionTo('student')

 `export default IndexRoute`
```

My *routes/settings.coffee* file:

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`

SettingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend()

`export default SettingsRoute`
```

My *routes/student.coffee* file:

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`

StudentRoute = Ember.Route.extend()

`export default StudentRoute`
```

My *environment.js* file:

```
    /* jshint node: true */

module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'something-frontend',
    environment: environment,
    rootURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
        // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
        // e.g. 'with-controller': true
      }
    },

    APP: {
      // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
      // when it is created
    }
  };

  if (environment === 'development') {
    // ENV.APP.LOG_RESOLVER = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = true;
  }

  if (environment === 'test') {
    // Testem prefers this...
    ENV.baseURL = '/';
    ENV.locationType = 'none';

    // keep test console output quieter
    ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = false;
    ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = false;

    ENV.APP.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
  }

  if (environment === 'production') {
      ENV.location = 'hash';
      ENV.rootURL = '/~somebody/dist'
  }

  return ENV;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I solved the problem with setting the locationType to hash in environment.js.
`locationType: 'hash'`

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Location.html#toc_hashlocation

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a setting route to let your application goes to. Please make sure that you have routes/settings.js file.

Comment: I have that file. I have those files for all of my routes. I edited my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with ember, but rather the http server configuration. You should configure your http server to redirect all requests not matching a file to index.html.

In nginx you can use the following:

```
location /~user/dist/ {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?/$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't have to try this at the end, because I found a 'workaround' in Ember. :)